# It is true that $\mathrm {Im}(f^{n_{0}})=\mathrm {Im}(f^m)$ for all $m\geq n_0$ implies $\mathrm {Im}(f^{n_{0}})=\{0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a  finite abelian group, and $f: G\longrightarrow G$ an endomorphisme of $G,$ such that $\ker(f)\neq \{0\},$ and $\mathrm {Im}(f)$ a propre subgroup  of $G,$ so we have a descending chain :$$...\subset\mathrm {Im}(f^n)...\mathrm {Im}(f^2)\subset\mathrm {Im}(f^2)\subset \mathrm {Im}(f).$$
but since $G$ is finite there is some integer $n_0\in \mathbb N^*$ such that : $\mathrm {Im}(f^{n_{0}})=\mathrm {Im}(f^m)$ for all $m\geq n_0.$

It is true that the last condition implies $\mathrm {Im}(f^{n_{0}})=\{0\}.$ ?

Under what conditions this is true ?

Comment: $G = C_2\times C_2,\; f(x,y) = (0,y)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer,Thanks for the counter example. Under what conditions the result is true ?

Comment: You start wih any endomorphism which is not an isomorphism. What condition do you expect which ensure that it is nilpotent? Do you have a feeling for the case of vector spaces? What does that tell you?

Comment: If $f$ is monomorphism , then it implies that $f$ is a surjrctive map.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg ; I want a sufficient condition for an endomorphism ( not an isomorphism) of abelian group is nilpotent .